# stack overflow c copystring with pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, copy

I'm writing a recursive copystring function in c and I'm receiving a write access violation. The funcion doesn't terminate when the function reaches the final letter in the string.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char*, char*, int);

int main()
{
    char str1[10] = { 'H', 'e', ' j',' h','e', 'j' };
    char str2[10] = { '/0' };

    copy(str1, str2, 0);
    printf(str2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void copy(char* str1, char* str2, int index) {
    while (str1[index] != '/0') {
        str2[index] = str1[index];
        index++;
        copy(str1, str2, index);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Where's your null termination in str1?

Comment: `'/0'`  ----> `'\0'` or just `while (str1[index])` And why the recursive call?

Comment: `' j'` has a space (it shouldn't). `char str1[10] = "Hejhej";` would solve a few problems at once.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks, the change to '\0' worked. It was a question on a previous exam and they wanted a recursive copy function.

Comment: If you want it to be recursive, remove the `while`. Just make sure to terminate the recursion properly.

Comment: @UKMonkey It comes implicit: "All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are initialized implicitly the same way as objects that have static storage duration."

Comment: @4386427 and there was me thinking that was a c++ thing only... good to know; thanks :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I changed the while to if and it is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three main problems here:

1) You use `'/0'` when it should be `'\0'`

2) You have extra spaces in the initializer, i.e. `' j'` and `' h'`.

3) Your recursive function isn't really doing what you want - don't use a `while`. It shall only copy one char and then do the recursive call until it meets a `'\0'`

The code should rather look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char*, char*, int);

int main()
{
    char str1[10] = { 'H', 'e', 'j','h','e', 'j' };
                         //     ^^   ^^ removed extra spce

    char str2[10];  // No initialization needed

    copy(str1, str2, 0);
    printf(str2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void copy(char* str1, char* str2, int index) {
    str2[index] = str1[index];

    // Have we reached end?
    if (str1[index] != '\0') {
        // No - so call again
        index++;
        copy(str1, str2, index);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems.

1) `\0` (null byte) is not same as `/0`. C-strings are terminated with `\0` (or just 0) which is most certainly what you intended to use.

2) You have spaces in `' j'` and `' h'` - these are multi-byte characters. This is, again, probably not what you wanted. If your intention was to have space between chars,
then you need to:

```
char str1[] = { 'H', 'e', ' ', 'j',' ', 'h','e', 'j' };
```

or,

```
char str1[] = "He j h ej";
```

If not, remove the spaces from those two elements of `str1` array. You could write it as:

```
char str1[] = "Hejhej";
```

Also, it's better (less error prone) if you leave out the array dimension - compiler will allocate sufficient space. If you needed to know the size of the array then you can use `sizeof str1` to get it.

Your `copy` function doesn't need to `index` at all. Since you want to copy recursively, the use of while loop is also incorrect. So you could write it as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(const char*, char*);

int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = "Hejhej";
    /* Equivalent to:
     * char str1[] = { 'H', 'e', 'j', 'h', 'e', 'j', '\0' }; 
     */
    char str2[sizeof str1] = { '\0' };

    copy(str1, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str2);
    return 0;
}

void copy(const char *str1, char *str2)
{
    if (*str1) {
        *str2 = *str1;
        copy(++str1, ++str2);
    } else {
        /* This isn't strictly needed because the destination string `str2` contains null bytes. */
        *str2 = '\0';
    }
}
```